# Assigning a static IP on Ubuntu 18.04, on wifi i.e. wlp2s0

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my laptop. In which I am using internet through WLAN. As my IP changes upon connection with new wifi Networks, I want to make static IP. In short I want not my IP to be changed upon a new SSID. So far, I have searched, I have found tutorials of static IP configuration but for ethernet, not for Wifi. So please help, if somebody has any idea ?
Actually I need to make a DNS server

Comment: "I want not my IP to be changed upon a new SSID", you meant that you want to keep the same ip on different networks or in all wifi networks that it will connect?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to keep same ip, whether it is network or ssid. Please help me out

Comment: There's no solution that will work 100% of the time. You can have `192.168.0.x`, `192.168.1.x`, `10.11.x.x`, etc. [Private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). Now the question is why you **need** to keep the private ip across networks, there's maybe another solution for you problem/ibjective.

Answer (score 0):

- In Ubuntu desktop click the wifi/volume/power at the top right.
- Select your WiFi network and select "Wi-Fi Settings"
- Select the gear icon in the new window that pops up next to the network.
- Go to IPv4 or IPv6 tabs as required.
- Change from Automatic (DHCP) to Manual.
- Enter the IP address, Subnet Mask (usually 255.255.255.0 but may be different for your circumstance), and Gateway.
- You can also set your DNS servers here if you don't want to use those provided from your ISP.
- Repeat for each network.

If this solved your problem please mark it as the answer.